# How to replay messages with Quarkus/Smallrye Kafka Messaging?

Tags: smallrye-reactive-messaging

Is there a way to set the timestamp of the offset at which to start off at using Quarkus/Smallrye messaging?

Or to go back to any specific offset?

Answer (score 0):

Offsets are stored in kafka, you can reset a topic like this:

```
kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server <kafkahost:port> --group <group_id> --topic <topic_name> --reset-offsets --to-earliest --execute
```

Comment: I want to go to a specific offset and read back from that offset not from complete start.